# RequiredAction not deleted from admin UI

Tags: jboss, keycloak, redhat, keycloak-services

I removed VERIFY_EMAIL required action from user. It's has been deleted from database and user's field. BUT it is still on ADMIN UI. I can not understand why

```
@Override
public void sendVerifyEmail(String link, long expirationInMinutes) throws EmailException {
    Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>(this.attributes);
    addUserAttributes(user, attributes);
    addLinkInfoIntoAttributes(link, expirationInMinutes, attributes);
    attributes.put("realmName", getRealmName());

    // here I delete required action to not require a user to verify email before he can login
    user.removeRequiredAction(UserModel.RequiredAction.VERIFY_EMAIL);
    user.removeRequiredAction(UserModel.RequiredAction.VERIFY_EMAIL.name());

    send("emailVerificationSubject", EnvVariablesUtils.getVerifyEmailMailgunTemplate(), attributes);
}
```

Comment: Can you give some more context? Where do you see the required action in the admin UI? What are you trying to implement here? Is that some kind of SPI?

Comment: hey, did you manage to solve this? I'm facing a similar issue